# Les deux phrases dans lesquelles le participe présent est utilisé sont-elles correctes?

Tags: participe-présent, gérondif

Qu’est-ce qui justifie l’emploi du participe présent plutôt que du gérondif dans les deux phrases suivantes:

> 1- L’Univers a commencé dans un état incroyablement chaud et dense; ensuite, l’espace est entré en expansion, la matière s’est diluée et a refroidi, **passant par** (quelle est la valeur du participe présent, une cause ou une manière) diverses transitions.

> 2- Le trou noir va continuer à grossir, **avalant** (quelle est la valeur du participe présent, une cause ou une manière) toutes les malheureuses étoiles qui vont y tomber.

Voici mon approche visant à déterminer la valeur de la forme attendue. Il est possible qu’elle ne soit pas fiable. Ma stratégie est fort simple, elle consiste à poser des questions pertinentes via l’utilisation d’adverbes interrogatifs et  à chercher à y répondre avec les termes de la phrase dans l’éventualité où cela serait possible. (Je formule sûrement mal ce que je cherche à dire, n’hésitez pas à apporter des modifications pour éclaircir mon propos) Phrase 1: *Pourquoi* la matière s’est diluée et refroidie? *Parce qu*’elle est passée par diverses transitions. *Comment* la matière s’est diluée et refroidie? *En passant* par diverses transitions.
Phrase 2: Pourquoi le trou noir va-il continuer à grossir? *Parce qu*’il va avaler toutes les étoiles qui vont y tomber. *Comment* le trou noir va-t-il continuer à grossir? *En avalant* toutes les étoiles qui vont y tomber.

Le recours au gérondif dans ces deux phrases serait-il envisageable? Ce qui donnerait, après modification:

> L’Univers a commencé dans un état incroyablement chaud et dense; ensuite, l’espace est entré en expansion, la matière s’est diluée et a refroidi, **en passant par** diverses transitions.

> Le trou noir va continuer à grossir, **en avalant** toutes les malheureuses étoiles qui vont y tomber.

Edit: La valeur de la forme attendue dans la phrase réside, si l’on se réfère au contexte, dans la manière (gérondif) ou dans la cause (participe présent) , les deux peuvent donc être employés de manière équivalente.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour cette précision.

Comment: Comment auriez-vous exprimer mon approche? Il m’est difficile de mettre des mots sur ce que je cherche à dire dans cette situation, mais pas seulement…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La manière ne peut pas être rendue par un participe présent.

- Le restaurateur assurait le succès de son travail en prenant tout son temps.  (*manière*)
- Le restaurateur assurait le succès de son travail, prenant tout son temps. (*temps, simultanéité*)

1. 

> 1- L’Univers a commencé dans un état incroyablement chaud et dense; ensuite, l’espace est entré en expansion, la matière s’est diluée et a refroidi, passant par diverses transitions.
>
> Quelle est la valeur du participe présent, une cause ou une manière?

Il ne peut pas être question de manière ([Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/chroniq/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_titls&page=93HYa44F8eTc.html) (article à lire soigneusement vu la profondeur de l'aperçu qu'il fournit), [Français Facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-33370.php)). Il est utile de passer en revue l'article par Harald Gettrup  [Le gérondif, le participe présent et la notion de repère temporel, 1977](https://tidsskrift.dk/revue_romane/article/download/29228/26067?inline=1) ; comme l'article de J. Desrosiers il révèle une foule de nuances  sur le sujet du participe présent.

S'il y a  dans le contexte de la lecture la mention d'une cause à effet mettant en relation le refroidissement et le passage par diverses transitions, il n'est pas vraiment permis de conclure à une relation de cause, la raison de cela étant qu'il s'agirait d'une répétition. Si cette information n'a pas été donnée, savoir s'il s'agit de cause dépend du contexte « local » : il n'existe rien dans l'acquis existentiel qui permette de dire qu'une relation de cause à effet existe entre le fait de passer par des transitions et de refroidir. On ne peut donc conclure autre chose que la notion exprimée est celle de circonstance concomitante.

L'approche qui est adoptée dans le PO est celle de l'astrophysicien et elle n'est d'aucun secours. La seule approche se situe sur le plan de l'information connue et de la communication d'information nouvelle qui doit être communiquée sur la base de cette information, l'information nouvelle étant encore de l'information connue, mais seulement du point de vue du locuteur.

Si l'information nouvelle (à communiquer au lecteur) serait que le refroidissement se fait par le truchement de transitions—et cela semblerait être le cas—, alors il ne s'agit pas vraiment de manière mais de moyen, ou plus précisément encore, d'instrument (au sens grammatical). Ce complément d'instrument s'exprime sans problème avec un  gérondif, mais dans ce contexte pas de façon univoque ; les possibilités sont ouvertes et une simple conclusion que les transitions sont une circonstance concomitante est toujours possible ; il appartient au locuteur de rendre précis par la suite ce qu'il entend par ce gérondif.

- L’Univers a commencé dans un état incroyablement chaud et dense; ensuite, l’espace est entré en expansion, la matière s’est diluée et a refroidi *en passant par diverses transitions*.
- L’Univers a commencé dans un état incroyablement chaud et dense; ensuite, l’espace est entré en expansion, la matière s’est diluée et a refroidi *en passant par diverses transitions*. Ces transitions ont un effet très rapide sur le refroidissement. (*par exemple*)

2. 

> 2- Le trou noir va continuer à grossir, avalant toutes les malheureuses étoiles qui vont y tomber.
>
> Quelle est la valeur du participe présent, une cause ou une manière ?

Pour cette seconde phrase, il n'y a pas de changement avec l'explication précédente excepté qu'il ne s'agit plus d'instrument à mon avis, mais de moyen.

Comment: Quelle serait votre façon de décrire mon approche? Je suis maintenant conscient qu’elle n’est pas pertinente à l’en croire à votre réponse, mais je tiens tout de même à savoir comment vous l’auriez présentée dans vos propres mots: j’ai consacré plusieurs minutes à essayer de la mettre en mots sans pourtant avoir l’impression qu’elle est compréhensible et qu’elle rend l’idée attendue.

Comment: Et au passage, auriez-vous une idée d'un éventuel trouble qui pourrait expliquer pourquoi j'interprète les choses différemment de vous (je vois une valeur de manière là où vous y voyez une valeur de moyen ou d’instrument) et pourquoi j'ai des difficultés à exprimer mes pensées clairement? Je vous demande simplement votre avis personnel basé sur vos connaissances actuelles, pas un diagnostic.

Comment: @Antivlad Les commentaires en retour prennent beaucoup trop de place et ne vont pas vraiment dans la réponse ; je les place sur la page discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Le participe présent fonctionne comme un adverbe invariable. Il qualifie un nom ou un pronom. Le gérondif, lui, modifie un verbe. Il exprime la simultanéité ou la manière.

Dans la première phrase:

> La matière s’est diluée et a refroidi, passant par diverses transitions.

C'est la matière qui passe par diverses transitions. Le verbe "passer" se réfère donc bien à un nom, il s'agit d'un participe présent. L'emploi du gérondif est possible dans la mesure où l'on considère que "en passant" modifie la manière dont la matière "est" : C'est en passant par diverses transitions que la matière s'est diluée et a refroidi. Il ne reste plus qu'à faire une ellipse du verbe être, et intervertir les propositions, pour obtenir la construction proposée : La matière s'est diluée et a refroidi en passant par diverses transitions.

> Le trou noir va continuer à grossir, avalant toutes les malheureuses étoiles qui vont y tomber.

La construction est identique : avaler fait référence au trou noir (un nom) ; le gérondif provoque l'emploi du verbe être pour désigner la manière dont cela est : C'est en avalant que …

L'emploi de l'un plutôt que l'autre est une histoire de style. La construction au participe présent semble toutefois plus simple, grammaticalement.

Comment: Je ne pense pas qu’il soit question d’une ellipse du verbe être.  La construction « c’est + …+ que » sert à mettre en évidence un complément ou un groupe de mots. Si on ne cherche pas à l’encadrer, on se retrouve avec la phrase originale.

Comment: Dans les faits, on se passe de la mise en relief, on n’est pas face à une ellipse.